# UI Scaled incorrectly in Gazebo 8 and 9 on macOS Mojave (10.14.1) and low frame rate

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.1 on a mid-2014 MacBook Pro. I installed using homebrew.

Gazebo 8 and 9 both open up with huge scaling issues on the UI (both with macOS default scaling and "More Space" scaling).

The frame rate seems excessively low and the mouse does not line up with highlighting of the menu items. Gazebo 7 opens up with the correct UI scaling, but I cannot get the world to render (just get a black screen).

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/nju8h0C.png)

Here is the console output from running the program:

```
~> gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 8.6.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 8.6.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
[Msg] Publicized address: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
[Msg] Publicized address: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21211/ui-scaled-incorrectly-in-gazebo-8-and-9-on-macos-mojave-(10.14.1)-and-low-frame-rate./) by [variable](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7373/variable/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a known issue, you can see progress [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2531/gazebo-gui-rendering-is-scaled).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [variable](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7373/variable/) on 2018-11-28**:
Great. Thanks.